# Resizing Marker Image dynamically in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have added a marker on Google Map. Is there any way I can resize marker image once it is placed on Google Map just like a Rectangle is resizable by setting `editable: true`.

I know there are `scaledSize` and `size` properties to set size of Marker Image but I don't know new size of image. How can I make marker resizable?

Here is sample code I am using. I took this from Maps documentation section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Markers are not editable.  You can change the size, but you need to write code to modify the icon of the marker to do that.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did something on my own to resize marker image. I thought I should post answer if somebody else encounter same thing.

I used `icon` to set marker's image properties. Than I created two functions `decSize(marker)` and `incSize(marker)` and used this logic to change size. I don't know if it will server purpose for every user but its working for me.

```
function createMarker() {
   var myIcon = {
       url: "car.png", //url
       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50) };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location, 
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
  icon:myIcon
  });
}


//Definition of decSize function. 
//This function is triggered through some button onClick listener.
function decSize(marker) {
   var oldIcon = marker.getIcon(); 
   var size_x = oldIcon.scaledSize.width;
   var size_y = oldIcon.scaledSize.height;
   var newIcon = {url: oldIcon.url, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(size_x-1,size_y-1)};
   marker.setIcon(newIcon);
}
```